# Magento Event Observer to group product collection by category

Tags: php, magento, events, group-by, observers

I'm creating an events observer module which will group upsell products by category,

below is my module's model/observer.php file,

```
public function updateUpsells($observer)
    {
        $iCurrentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $oUpsellCollection = $event->getCollection();
        foreach ($oUpsellCollection->getItems() as $key => $oUpsellProduct) {
            $aCategoriesIds = $oUpsellProduct->getCategoryIds();
            if (!in_array($iCurrentCategory, $aCategoriesIds)) {
                $oUpsellCollection->removeItemByKey($key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After enabling this module i can include `upsell product's category id's` in `upsell.phtml` file by echo `$this->getItemCollection()->getItems()`

as a result i got,

```
    Array
(
    [170] => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product Object
        ( 
           .........................
           [_data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [entity_id] => 170
                    [entity_type_id] => 10
                    [attribute_set_id] => 44
                    [type_id] => simple
                    [category_ids] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 12
                            [1] => 26
                        )
                    .......................

           )
    [171] => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product Object
        ( 
           .........................
           [_data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [entity_id] => 171
                    [entity_type_id] => 10
                    [attribute_set_id] => 44
                    [type_id] => simple
                    [category_ids] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 16
                            [1] => 24
                        )
                    .......................

           )
)
```

So now how can i group this array results by category. Example mentioned 2 upsell products assigned to 4 different categories, as a result i need to group products like,

```
Category id 12
  product1 | Product2

Category id 26
  product1 | Product2
```